# Average all of elements of list A which whose indices have the same value in list B

Tags: python, numpy

```
values_array = np.array([2,4,6])
coords_array = np.array([[127,130,130],[127,130,130],[128,131,132]])
```

Each element v in values_array has a "coordinate" c at the same position in coords_array.

I need a mapping from unique coordinate c to the average of all values which have that coordinate.  For the example that would be

```
mapping[[127,130,130]] = np.mean([2,4])
mapping[[128,131,132]] = np.mean([6])
```

Without worrying about speed, I would do:

```
mapping = {}
for coordinate in np.unique(coords_array):
    indices = np.where(coords_array==coordinate)
    mapping[coordinate] = np.mean(values_array[indices])
```

I really need to do it without the loop in python if at all possible though.

Comment: Well ideally I need a 3D numpy array a where a[coord] = mean(values)

Answer (score 0):

We could use `np.unique` to tag each unique color and then `bincount` to get labeled average values -

```
In [145]: u,t = np.unique(coords_array, axis=0, return_inverse=True)

# Unique avg colors
In [146]: u
Out[146]: 
array([[127, 130, 130],
       [128, 131, 132]])

# Avg values    
In [147]: np.bincount(t, values_array)/np.bincount(t)
Out[147]: array([3., 6.])
```

Or additionally, use `return_counts` arg to get counts directly -

```
In [156]: u,t,c = np.unique(coords_array, axis=0, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)

In [159]: np.bincount(t, values_array)/c
Out[159]: array([3., 6.])
```

So, if you need to assign these average values into a 3D array `a`, simply do -

```
a[tuple(u.T)] = avg # avg are average values from bincount output
```

Comment: I have to say I couldn't nake that work.  Bincount doesn't like the "colours" being a list in my implementation.

Comment: @Omroth You need to elaborate on "doesn't like" part. Some error? Any reproducible example to show us the error?

Comment: I ended up implementing it just via loop, which was fast enough - if I get time tomorrow I'll try and replicate the error I had with bincount